# Find external and internal devices attached to a system in Linux

Tags: linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find external and internal devices attached to a system in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/113086/find-external-and-internal-devices-attached-to-a-system-in-linux)

How can i find through terminal that which devices are external and which are internal.

By external i mean devices attached to USB port. For Example, USB Drive, Portable USB HardDrive etc

By internal i mean devices attached internally. For Example, SATA Harddisk etc.

Thanks

Comment: exact duplicate (user crossposted): http://superuser.com/questions/113086/find-external-and-internal-devices-attached-to-a-system-in-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `lsusb` to list USB devices, `lspci` to list PCI devices, and `lspcmcia` to list PCMCIA devices.

If you only care about disk-type devices, you can also look into `/dev/disk/by-id`. The link name of the device start with the connection type (usb, ata, scsi-sata, etc.)

Comment: I'm lazy, so I always look into /proc/partitions to get an idea of any attached and usable block devices.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't in general possible - lots of machines have internal USB devices (things like Bluetooth interfaces and fingerprint readers are often implemented in this way), and it's possible to have external SATA devices (the laptop I'm using now has an eSATA port).  SCSI devices can also be internal or external.

Answer (score 0):

Block devices have a "removable" attribute.  While this does not exactly correspond to internal/external (e.g. an internal CDROM is "removable" and an eSATA drive may be misclassified), it may be close enough for your purposes.

```
$ cd /sys/block/
$ grep ^ */removable
dm-0/removable:0
dm-1/removable:0
dm-2/removable:0
dm-3/removable:0
dm-4/removable:0
dm-5/removable:0
dm-6/removable:0
dm-7/removable:0
dm-8/removable:0
fd0/removable:1
hdc/removable:1
loop0/removable:0
loop1/removable:0
loop2/removable:0
loop3/removable:0
loop4/removable:0
loop5/removable:0
loop6/removable:0
loop7/removable:0
md0/removable:0
md1/removable:0
sda/removable:0
sdb/removable:0
sdc/removable:0
sdd/removable:0
sde/removable:1
sdf/removable:1
sdg/removable:1
sdh/removable:1
sdi/removable:1
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a small script example using [HAL](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal) , if you have it.

```
store=$(hal-find-by-capability --capability "storage")
for s in $store
do
  r=$(hal-get-property --udi ${s} --key storage.removable)
  if [ $r = "true" ]; then
    hal-get-property --udi ${s} --key info.product
    prod=$(hal-get-property --udi ${s} --key info.product)
    type=$(hal-get-property --udi ${s} --key storage.drive_type)
    device=$(hal-get-property --udi ${s} --key block.device)
    mdir=$(awk -vdev="$device" '$0~dev{print $2}' /etc/mtab)
    echo Product: ${prod}
    echo Type: ${type}
    echo Mounted on: ${mdir}
  fi
done

vol=$(hal-find-by-capability --capability "volume")
for v in $vol
do
   mountpt=$(hal-get-property --udi ${v} --key volume.mount_point)
   blk=$( hal-get-property --udi ${v} --key block.device )
   echo "mount point: $mountpt"
   echo "device: $blk"
done
```

Use `hal-device` command to show HAL devices.

Comment: Yay.  Now, any idea how to do this with http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/DeviceKit HAL's replacement?  :-/

Comment: I looked at the page, its new i guess. no idea how.